# Set button content to uppercase

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a specific button content where Tx is a UTExtension to get string by key. How to convert string to Uppercase.

```
<Button
     Style="{StaticResource ButtonHomePageLeft}"
     Content="{Tx:UT Key=Tx:homepage.button.info}"/>
```

I tried this way but It throw an exception

```
<Button
     Style="{StaticResource ButtonHomePageLeft}"
     Content="{Bindin Path={Tx:UT Key=Tx:homepage.button.info},
                      Converter={StaticResource ToUpperCaseConverter}}"/>
```

Sorry that I wasn't specific in my question. Even when I use code in this way I'm getting an exception.

```
 <Button
    Style="{StaticResource ButtonHomePageRight}">
    <Button.Content>
          <Binding>
               <Binding.Path>
                    <Tx:UT Key="Tx:homepage.button.use"/>
               </Binding.Path>
          </Binding>
    </Button.Content>
 </Button>
```

And the error I got.
[image]

Comment: u cannot set Path property like you set. What is Tx? is there any static property you want to bind to?

Answer (score 4):

You may try Typography.Capitals property of Button:

```
<Button Typography.Capitals="AllSmallCaps"></Button>
```